# Using IEnumerable<> as a parameter for a generic method that can get reference and non reference type

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to build a validation attribute that will validate the size of a collection,
I want the method to be able to handle reference types like string and also non reference types like int. I tried to use `IEnumerable<object>` but that stays null in case I pass a `IEnumerable<int>`.

This is my current code -

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter | AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class EnumerableSizeAttribute : ValidationAttribute<IEnumerable<object>>
{
 
    protected override ValidationResult? IsValid(IEnumerable<object>? enumerable, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
    //check collection size
    }
}
```

What should I use as parameter to allow me to pass any collection type into the method?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to use a generic parameter for  `IsValid`. C# 11 allows you to specify generic attributes.

Comment: You mean that the same list can contain items of different types? That's the opposite of `a generic method`. In that case you can use `IEnumerable` and check whether `enumerable` is an `IList` so you can use the cheap `Count` property. It doesn't matter whether the types are value or reference types, what matters is the same list contains different types, eg `int` and `double`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generic variance rules between value and reference types are... complex.

If you need to avoid boxing, then consider making the method itself generic and take `IEnumerable<T>`, so that the caller specifies it (usually implicitly, so no code change).

If that isn't an option: consider using the non-generic `IEnumerable` APIs. Or `IList` or `ICollection` since you're after the count, which you can then access cheaply via `.Count` without paying any of the boxing / iteration overheads associated with `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @NGDeveloper to use `IEnumerable<T>` for unknown `T` without boxing, you need the method to be generic (or it needs to be a non-generic method in a generic type, like in Panagiotis' answer)

Answer (score 2):

In C# 11/.NET 7 and later you can have [generic attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-11#generic-attributes) :

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter | AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class EnumerableSizeAttribute<T> : ValidationAttribute<IEnumerable<T>>
{
 
    protected override ValidationResult? IsValid(IEnumerable<T>? enumerable, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
    //check collection size
    }
}
```

Inside `IsValid` you can check whether `enumerable` is an `ICollection<T>`, thus using the cheap `Count` property to check the size :

```
if(enumerable is ICollection<T> col && col.Count <...)
{
    
}
```

You may be able to use property pattern matching too, although I'm still not comfortable with the syntax. Something like

```
if(enumerable is ICollection<T> {Count: < MaxLength} col)
{
    
}
```